# Google Maps API - Display/Add custom location (marker)

Tags: html, google-maps

I want to display a custom location with an icon and a label on the Google map in my web site.

Comment: do you need to display the map or text link

Comment: I want to display map with that custom link.

Answer (score 0):

In the head section Insert the following JS library and the coding. Change LatLng to match your exact location.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(7.316306, 80.622160);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'My new location is this :P'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

And in the body section insert this div where you want the map to be displayed.

```
<div id="map-canvas" width="350" height="271"></div>
```

Comment: I want to put my location link instead of LatLng.

Comment: ooops!!!!   just replace the values in my example(7.31... & 80.62...) with your own values that points to your exact location. You can find the exact values from the Google map by right click -> my location..

Comment: This is the link and i want to show the exact map into my website.https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Howrah,+Station+Road,+Howrah+Railway+Station,+West+Bengal,+India/South+City+Mall,+375,+Prince+Anwar+Shah+Road,+Jadavpur,+Kolkata,+West+Bengal+700068,+India/@22.5440264,88.3041789,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x3a027795d8ab719b:0x45ef375a63fd05f3!2m2!1d88.3412374!2d22.5841579!1m5!1m1!1s0x3a0270d861b6d22b:0xee3d107a198d3cdf!2m2!1d88.3618516!2d22.5014411!3e0